# Whitelabel Error Page - Error in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, microservices, spring-tool-suite

I am getting "Whitelabel Error Page" while running Spring Boot Application, even after mapping the URLs.

I have mentioned my application.properties file and one controller file

```
application.properties file

server.port=8087
server.servlet.context-path=/starts

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

---------------------------------------------

TestController.java file

package com.example.firstproject.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.firstproject.Entity.Employee;
import com.example.firstproject.Service.EmployeeService;

@RestController

public class TestController {
@Autowired
EmployeeService empService;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public int test(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return empService.saveEmployee(emp);
        //return 0;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Employee> home() {
        return empService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I have also attached the image of error which I was getting while running the project
[Whitelabel Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIA8.png)

How should I remove this error?

Comment: ok, and what exactly is your question?

Comment: You're still not clear. Do you want to avoid getting an error, or do you want a nice-looking error page?

Comment: I want to avoid error @Stultuske

Answer (score 1):

Your /save mapping is a POST request and requires a Employee object. you can't call it from browser URL. Browser calls are GET request only. You should use some tool like Postman to send a POST request.

Comment: did you add json request object in request body and select POST as a request method? And Please annotate @POST Or @PostMapping(path= "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") annotation in your  controller.

Comment: I have tried doing that, but the whitelabel error still exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the type of RequestMapping you are doing
`@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
or
`PostMapping("/save")`

Comment: did you add the **content-type** headers as **application/json** also, can you post the postman request ?

Comment: yes, I have added the content-type value as application/json
My postman request is - http://localhost:8087/save